# Is it possible to predict release of acid fumes in certain acid reactions?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, reaction-control

Upon mixing both acids, the reaction between Formic Acid and Sulfuric Acid, besides producing Carbon Monoxide and Water, releases a certain amount of acid fumes.

Does anyone know if the fumes, in that specific reaction, are of only one of the acids or both of them?

Also, is there a good way to predict release of acid fumes in similar reactions? Is it a characteristic of certain acids?

Thank you.

Comment: It is probably just hot water vapor and some entrained tiny droplets of the acids. It may not always be easy to predict when significant fuming is likely, but it is always possible to predict that using a working fume hood is a great idea.

Comment: Note that formic acid  releases carbon monoxide even spontaneously, what is reason it should not be stored in a gas tight containers.

Comment: Partly related: [Making carbon monoxide gas from formic acid and sulfuric acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34130/7951) and [Vaporized sodium hydroxide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31569/7951)

Answer (score 2):

Formic acid is volatile.

Any volatile liquid, including water, if heated ( externally or spontaneously in mixture ) forms fumes, if temperature in gas above the liquid drops below its dew point.

Remember water "fumes" over a boiling kettle.

Additionally to these physical-chemical reasons, if there is boiling (or other strong mechanical disturbance)  instead of plain  evaporation, the non volatile sulphuric acid can pass  to fumes by mechanical way.

Comment: Perhaps boiling kettle? :-)

Comment: @Ed V Sure, kettle. :-D As non native, even if I know both words, I may confuse them as almost homophones.  :-)